# How to deal with a Java Processes grandchilds when reading the output?

Tags: java, multithreading, process, stream

Working on a JavaFX mockup of a commandline I encountered the following problem:
If I run a process (for example a batchfile) that runs another process (for example opens the notepad with a simple `start notepad`) I cannot seem to properly determine when the batch-file is done executing:

- [Process#waitFor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor--) already returns when the batchfiles is started (I guess because I have to add `cmd /c` in front of the executable and cmd really is done after a short fraction of a second)
- Reading the output using the [Process#getInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getInputStream--) only ends after I close the notepad not after the batchfile terminates.

Is there a method I keep missing? And more importantly: How can I determine the end of the process spawned through `cmd /c` if at all?

Reproducible example:

example.bat:

```
@echo off
start notepad
REM You can change the path to something else but it should be something where tree produces a longer output to reproduce the problem.
cd %USERPROFILE%\Desktop
tree
```

JavaCode:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Process myProcess = null;
        try {
            myProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c C:\\Users\\geisterfurz007\\Desktop\\example.bat");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        startReadingThread(myProcess);

        try {
            myProcess.waitFor();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Process ended");
    }

    private static void startReadingThread(Process myProcess) {
        InputStream stream = myProcess.getInputStream();
        new Thread(() -> {
            int character;
            try {
                while ((character = stream.read()) != -1) {
                    System.out.write(character);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    System.out.println("Reading ended");
                    stream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

}
```

starts printing the tree and mid printing "Process ended" is written to the console. Lastly "Reading ended" is printed **after** I close the notepad window.
My goal is to find the point where tree is done printing (ie the batchfile done processing) ignoring when the notepad was closed.

Based on [Leviands's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51536920/6707985) I tried to close the Processes streams once it was done executing to no avail.
The InputStream closes unfortunately mid content again and the ErrorStream (which I read in the actual application as well) won't close thus blocking the thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all a huge thanks to [Leviand](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1984767/leviand) who mentioned [InputStream#available](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#available--) in their [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51536920/6707985) which got me something that actually appears to work:

The idea is that at the point in time I am looking for, Process#isAlive should return false as the Stream takes longer to process than the Process processes (if that makes sense) while there should be no characters readable from the InputStream, so InputStream#available should return 0.

This leads to this piece of code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Process myProcess = null;
        try {
            myProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c C:\\Users\\geisterfurz007\\Desktop\\example.bat");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        startReadingThread(myProcess).start();
    }

    private static Thread startReadingThread(Process myProcess) {
        InputStream stream = myProcess.getInputStream();
        return new Thread(() -> {
            int character;
            try {
                while (myProcess.isAlive() || stream.available() > 0) {

                    if ((character = stream.read()) == -1) {
                        break;
                    }
                    System.out.write(character);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    stream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

With the code above I am able to achieve reading from the Processes stream ignoring any grandchild processes.

---

After some time using this, there are a few things to address:

- I moved to using an InputStreamReader now for one main reason: I can specify encoding. All occurences of `stream.available() > 0` would then have to be replaced with `reader.ready()`.
- This eats a bunch of resources when idling! It makes sense to have the thread sleep for a few milliseconds if there is nothing to read before attempting to read again.
- At least in my usecase where I send each character to my GUI one by one, this kills the GUI pretty quickly for longer outputs. Consider some kind of buffer for the output before further processing on your primary thread.

Comment: glad that you solved :) Hope I deserve at least an upvote ;) See you!

Answer (score 1):

You are launching `startReadingThread(myProcess);`, then you are telling with `myProcess.waitFor();` to wait that process `myProcess` is ended before printing `System.out.println("Reading ended");` , which is the opposite that you are willing to do.

The process that should "block" the other from starting is the `startReadingThread`.

The problem also look in the while loop, which was not correct.
I would change in something like (not sure on `stream.available() != 0`, but it's working for testing):

```
    private static Thread startReadingThread(Process myProcess) {
    InputStream stream = myProcess.getInputStream();
    return new Thread(() -> {
        int character;
        try {
            while (stream.available() != 0) {
                if((character = stream.read()) == -1) {
                    System.out.write(character);
                    stream.close();
                    break;
                }
                System.out.write(character);
            }
            stream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                System.out.println("Reading ended");
                stream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Then edit the main with:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Process myProcess = null;
    try {
        myProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c C:\\Users\\geisterfurz007\\Desktop\\example.bat");
           } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        if(myProcess.waitFor() == 0){
            startReadingThread(myProcess).start();
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Process ended");
```

output (I'm from italy):

> Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:56607', transport:
>   'socket' **Process ended** Elenco del percorso delle cartelle per il
>   volume OSDisk Numero di serie del volume: 12DA-8173 C:. Non esistono
>   sottocartelle
>
> **Reading ended** Disconnected from the target VM, address:
>   '127.0.0.1:56607', transport: 'socket'
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

**EDIT:**
Here's the test on a folder with subfolders inside (I'm attaching screenshot cause of strange symbols)

[image: test result]

And this is the folder content:

[image: folder content]

Comment: There are a few problems I have with this. First of all: I don't get any output at all anymore and the program appears to have locked up on Process#waitFor. Secondly: This would postpone the printing of the output a command has caused to after its execution or not? However I also require things like a logging executable to be run in there which continues piping the output to the console.

Comment: Interestingly I don't get any output for my original code anymore either. God knows why.

Comment: I've just tried again and I get the posted output... I can make a video if you want :)

Comment: Alright, I got at least my code to work again like it was when I posted. After experimenting a bit with the batchfile, I have to ask you to have the cd command change the directory to one that contains a few dozen subdirectories (at least my Desktop seems to contain enough that the Process gets stuck. Possibly because the stream buffer is full and further execution is limited?). And while this way I get the output and the program terminates despite the notepad showing, it is still only after full completion of the program which may not always be given (see my first comment).

Comment: @geisterfurz007 sure: I've done the test, I',ll post the screenshots in my answar because I get strange symbols

Comment: Don't worry about those too much. That happens mainly because the Charset isn't set properly :)